# Python- Simple random selector

Tags: python, random

I am creating a simple game in python where it asks you questions and then uses the answers to fill in the gaps in a story. I want to make it so that it will ask the questions in a random order each time but I want to have all of the questions asked.

I am using python 2.7.8 on Mac OSX and would like to know what I can do to get this result?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Code below if it helps :

```
while True: 

    print "Welcome to Consequences"
    print ' '
    print "Game is more fun in groups!"
    print''
    print "Group instructions :"
    print "Get in a circle and let each person enter one thing each without the rest of the group seeing    what they enter"
    print ' '
    print ' '
    print raw_input("Press enter to start")
    hide(str)

    nameb = raw_input("Enter a boys name then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    nameg = raw_input("Enter a girls name then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    place = raw_input("Enter a place that two people meet then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    saidtg = raw_input("Enter what the boy said to the girl then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    saidtb = raw_input("Enter what the girl said to the boy and then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    end = raw_input("Enter what happened in the end and then press enter ")

    hide(str)

    print "Here is your story:"
    print ' '
    print nameb, "met", nameg
    print "they met at", place
    print "then",nameb,"said to", nameg, saidtg
    print "then",nameg,"replied with", saidtb
    print "in the end", end

    raw_input("Press enter to start again")
    print ' '
    print ' '
    print ' '
    print ' '
```

Comment: Very clever that you used `while True` but you forgot to indent it accordingly I guess. All the statements following `while True` are outside that while loop.

Comment: sorry about that , I must have entered it wrong into the post but i do have the statements indented in my actual code. Must have done something wrong when copying it over.

Comment: Is that so ? I can edit for you properly for you so other members don't point it out.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is likely to be downvoted. It is too general, doesn't really show any attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: I apologise for the poor question but I'm pretty new to this and had yes that would be great sammy :)

Comment: For some reason I can't edit the question/code you posted Ed Edward Tervit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the questions in a list and use a dictionnary to store the variables:

```
questions = [('Enter name of boy', 'nameb') , ('Enter place', 'place'),...]
```

then shuffle the list and ask for each questions:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(questions,random.random) #shuffle list in place
>>> d = {}
>>> for (q,v) in questions:
...    d[v] = raw_input(q)
...    #more stuff like hide(str)
```

Then instead of:

```
print nameb, "met", nameg
print "they met at", place
```

You only have to do

```
print d['nameb'], "met", d['nameg']
print "they met at", d['place']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will need to get my head around this as I am new to python and coding but I'm sure I will eventually.

Comment: I think i understand everything apart from this part :

    d = {}
    >>> for q in questions:
    ...    d[q[1]] = raw_input(q[0])

Comment: @EdEdwardTervit I change it a little: `d={}` creates a new dict. `for (q,v) in questions` loop for all the questions/variables name and assign the question to q, the name to v. Then `d[v] = raw_input(q)` asks `q` and put the answer into the dict, at the key `v`.